# Stretch height of content-div so vertical-navi gets stretched as well

Tags: html, css

i have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z715whdj/1/ don't know what you need from css so please take a look at the fiddle.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="head">
    <!-- Slogen and meta-links -->
</div>
<div class="carousel">
    <!-- Maybe some headpics or a slider -->
</div>
<div class="logo">
    <!-- Main Logo -->
</div>
<div class="navi">
    <div class="logos">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <!-- Placeholder for some logos -->
        </ul>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <!-- Navi UL -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <!-- Content comes here -->
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <!-- Footer -->
</div>
</div>
```

the left blue bar should be the navi and it should be as high as the content+footer is (overlapping over footer). How can i get that?

I got the min-height aspect but it seems to be struggling because i get a scrollbar. i read through some of the questions here but i wasn't able to get some aspects of them.

is there a possibility to stretch the height of the navi in function of the content+footer or do i have to write a workaround and if i have to, how to write this workaround?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? IE 6 / 7 / 8 / 9 ?

Comment: IE8-11 should work. IE7 would be awesome.

Comment: use proper "float" property and "clearfix" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `position:relative` to container and `position:absolute` for navi. Set `top` property to compensate header height, and `bottom` to 0 to let navi fullfill `container` height.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 970px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #575756;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.container .navi {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #233872;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z715whdj/2/)

**EDIT:**

As requested, I've created a new (simpler) layout to let container fullfill 100% height without vertical scrollbar: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u96n7592/2/)

Comment: thank you very much. And how do i get rid of the scrollbar? the height seems to be over 100%

Comment: The scrollbar appears because you've set html, body and container with 100% height. If you want to get rid of it, simply remove these properties: http://jsfiddle.net/z715whdj/3/

Comment: i know. but if i delete the .container-height property the navi won't extend even with content in it. i want it to extend, but only to the browser limit and not above that (so without a scrollbar - only add scrollbar if content is longer than monitor-height).

Comment: @Dustin: I've just created a new (simpler) layout structure to satisfy your last request. See answer edit section.

Comment: you are awesome. but in the fiddle the navi seems to be out of the container or do i have a browser-bug?

Comment: @Dustin: don't worry, it's inside. I've added a red border to container to show it here: http://jsfiddle.net/u96n7592/1/ The reason because you see gray background on content only is because I've added background colors to header, footer, navi. Just remove them and enjoy!

Comment: So i added this and the navi still seems to floating right near to the .container it should be above the container (thats why i used z-index).

Comment: Ok fixed that with "left:"-command. But if i add too much content to .content the site doesn't stretch. the footer stays where he is, and the text goes over the footer and over the container.

Comment: @Dustin: you're absolutely right! Here's the fiddle with corrections (I've also updated link in answer): http://jsfiddle.net/u96n7592/2/